# reflection method invocation for a dynamic object

Tags: java, reflection

I am creating a class (named haan.java) at runtime of my java application. 
    The object of this class is inserted in a Oracle Coherence Cache
    When I get an object(tempHaan) from the cache, it is of type haan. But when I try to invoke the method of this object(tempHaan), I am getting the error **"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class"**

Error occurs at the line **"Object invoke = methodgetHash.invoke(tempHaan, null);"**

```
PFB the code:

NamedCache cacheConn;
CacheFactory.ensureCluster();
NamedCache cacheConnHaan = CacheFactory.getCache("Haan");
Class cls = null;
File f = new File(rtomProperties.getPropertyValue("pojoToBuild"));

try {
    ClassLoader currentThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { f.toURI().toURL() },
        currentThreadClassLoader);
    Object tempHaan;
    cls = Class.forName(rtomProperties.getPropertyValue("pojoPackageLocation").concat(".haan"), true, cl);
    System.out.println("*************** the class is **********"
        + cls.newInstance().getClass().toString());
    System.out.println("******DONE LOADING");

    URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class clazz = URLClassLoader.class;

    // Use reflection
    Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
    m.setAccessible(true);
    URL ur = f.toURI().toURL();
    m.invoke(classLoader, new Object[] { ur });

    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("context.xml");

    tempHaan = cacheConnHaan.get(aan);

    System.out.println("*************AFTER" + tempHaan.getClass().toString());

    System.out.println("*************tempHaan: "+tempHaan.toString());
    Class[] paramObject = new Class[1];
    paramObject[0] = Object.class;
    Method methodgetHash = null;                            
    Class noparams[] = {}; 
    methodgetHash = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getHash", noparams);
    Object temp = cls.newInstance();

    Object invoke = methodgetHash.invoke(tempHaan, null);
    key = (String) invoke;

    System.out.println("key for the record: " + key);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("******not instantiated");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    System.out.println("Hash-Aan mapping not found for aan " + aan);
    continue;
}
```

Comment: What's the reason for all this? It seems overly complex and pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You dynamically create an `ULRClassLoader` for loading the class, i.e. the cached instance's class and the class you get the method to invoke from come from different classloaders leading to this error. You might get the declared method from the instance to be cached and cache it together with the instance or you retrieve the instance from the cache and get the method to be invoked by calling

```
Method methodgetHash = tempHaan.getDeclaredMethod("getHash", noparams);
```

Caching the method together with the class to be cached would come with a performance-improvement BTW.

Comment: Thank you @Lothar

Comment: The code that worked for me:ClassLoader currentThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
       URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) currentThreadClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
       cls = URLClassLoader.class;
       Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
       m.setAccessible(true);
       URL ur = f.toURI().toURL();
       m.invoke(classLoader, new Object[] { ur });     
       cls = Class.forName(rtomProperties.getPropertyValue("pojoPackageLocation").concat(".haan"),
         true, currentThreadClassLoader);

Comment: @Anjani Can you add that as another answer and accept it, in order to get this question off the list of unanswered questions?

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked for me:
ClassLoader currentThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                            URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) currentThreadClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
                            cls = URLClassLoader.class;
                            Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
                            m.setAccessible(true);
                            URL ur = f.toURI().toURL();
                            m.invoke(classLoader, new Object[] { ur });
                            cls = Class.forName(rtomProperties.getPropertyValue("pojoPackageLocation").concat(".haan"),
                                    true, currentThreadClassLoader);